# Tengo este error al publicar mi shinyapp en shinyapps.io : "An error has occurred The application failed to start. exit status 1"

Tags: r, aplicación-web, shiny

Mi app funciona bien localmente, pero cuando intento publicarla en shinyapps.io falla:
"An error has occurred The application failed to start.  exit status 1".

Para cargar los códigos utilizo:
est_crim <- read.csv("snic-provincias.csv")
provincias <- st_read("provincias.shp")

Y los paquetes:
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(shinydashboard)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.